# AWS lambda image not showing the latest code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I have a docker image for an AWS lambda function which just prints a "Welcome" message. I've set this up to run the lambda code whenever a file is uploaded to an S3 bucket(via CFN script).
The lambda image is successfully created.
When I uploaded a test file to S3 via CLI (using aws s3 cp command), I could see the cloudwatch logs for the lambda printing that "Welcome" line. So far good.
I added few more lines to the python file and pushed the image to ECR and when I tried to copy a file to the same S3 bucket, I am not seeing the newly added print statements from the lambda handler shown in cloudwatch logs.

This is the command in my Dockerfile

```
CMD [ "app.lambda_handler" ]
```

This is my app.py

```
import os
def lambda_handler(event, context) -> None:
    python_path = os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH')
    secretsmanager_client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
    secret_name = "dev-demo-lambda-secret"
    print('\nWelcome!!!!!')
```

This is my app.py after I added additional an additional print statement (which I am NOT seeing in cloudwatch logs output)

```
import os
def lambda_handler(event, context) -> None:
    python_path = os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH')
    secretsmanager_client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
    secret_name = "dev-demo-lambda-secret"
    print('\nWelcome!!!!!')
    print('\nevent = ', event)
```

This is my buildspec.yaml to create the lambda docker image.

```
- aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS -- 
password-stdin 3xxxxxxxxxxx0.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
- docker image build -t 359772415770.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demolambda:$MY_DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION .
- docker push 359772415770.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo-lambda:$MY_DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: See [Updating function code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-images.html#configuration-images-update).

Comment: Perfect, Thank you...so every time I make a change to my lambda image, should I create a new version of the image in ECR in order to see the latest changes?

Comment: The Lambda function is basically frozen when you deploy it or update it. So if you subsequently modify a pre-requisite, such as a container image, you need to update the Lambda function otherwise it will continue to use the previous, frozen image. This is actually an important safety mechanism, to ensure that your Lambda code is always exactly what you originally deployed and tested.

Comment: Thank you. Updating the lambda function when I modify the container image - Can this be done via cloudformation script?